# How to extract all the .crt files and private key from a .jks file?

Tags: certificate, private-key, jks

I have a .jks file that contains 5 .crt files and a private key and I want to extract all these 5 .crt files and also the private key from the .jks file. Is there a command to do that?

So my .jks file looks like that:

```
aaa, Dec 5, 2023, trustedCertEntry
Certificate fingerprint (SHA-256): ........
bbb, Dec 5, 2023, trustedCertEntry
Certificate fingerprint (SHA-256): ........
ccc, Dec 5, 2023, trustedCertEntry
Certificate fingerprint (SHA-256): ........
ddd, Dec 5, 2023, trustedCertEntry
Certificate fingerprint (SHA-256): ........
eee, Dec 5, 2023, trustedCertEntry
Certificate fingerprint (SHA-256): ........
fff, Dec 5, 2023, PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate fingerprint (SHA-256): ........
```

This .jks file was build from these 5 .crt files and the private key and now I want to obtain the 5 .crt files and the private key from this .jks file. So, I need a command to run it and to have 6 files, 5 .crt files and the private key. I need all these files because other people should have the possibility to recreate this .jks file using these files. Thank you!

Comment: Not programming or development, but: does 'jks' mean the specific format JKS or just some Java keystore? If you create(d) a keystore with `keytool` in Java 9 up, normally it is actually PKCS12 format and can be extracted to PEM with `openssl pkcs12 -in file` -- except if created with Java below 11.0.12 and reading with OpenSSL 3.0.0 up add `-legacy`. If it is really JKS, you must first use `keytool -importkeystore` to convert to PKCS12, then proceed as above. However, recreating even PKCS12 from PEM is harder; if you only use `openssl pkcs12 -export` trustedcert's won't work. ...

Comment: ... Alternatively the _progam_ keystore-explorer can do both directions easily, but it's a GUI not a command.

Comment: An X509 certificate should not be called "a .crt file". Just call it a *certificate*. Surely you ran the `keytool` command to get your output, so just look at the [documentation for the `keytool` command](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/keytool.html) to find out how to extract various pieces into files.